# Feynman physics on natural base $e$

Tags: mathematics

[image]

This is the way Feynman derived the natural base $e$ on Feynman lectures on physics. Could anyone explain the statement labeled by yellow? I don’t understand what it means by multiplying all the logarithms to the base 10.

Comment: I think what he's referring to is that we normally define the logarithm using the natural log i.e. $log_e$. However, we can now use properties of the log to derive all other logarithms: $log_a(b) = log_c(b)/log_c(a)$ (You can check this by explicitly taking the exponential on both sides) So what he means is basically that $log_e(10) = 2.3025 .... $  such that the base change works

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

He's just saying that
$$\ln x \equiv \log_e (x) = \frac{1}{\log_{10}(e)} \log_{10} (x) \approx 2.3025 \log_{10} (x)$$
which follows from the change of basis
$$ \log_a (x) = \frac{\log_b (x)}{\log_b (a)} $$
where he chose to change to the $\mathrm{e}$ basis

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you so much.